# Oracle Data Warehouse book for dummies

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse

I've been requested to study "the tools Oracle provides to create a data warehouse". I have studies basic DW concepts, data cubes, data mining, etc. in theory and I also know how to build a basic DW with a "classic" RDBMS like Access (OK let's say MySQL...)

Now it's time to get my hands on something more practical, so...

1. Can you suggest a few books, possibly free?
2. Does Oracle provide free tools to build a DW for demo/educational purposes?

Comment: Requests for book lists are not allowed on stack overflow.

Comment: Have you looked at Oracle's _2 Day + Data Warehousing Guide_? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/toc.htm

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Oracle's Warehouse Builder tool here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/warehouse/overview/introduction/index.html

They provide a self-learning guide and an SDK.

Also, in case you aren't familiar with the ETL(extract, transform and load) concept, it would be helpful as well to do some reading on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Oracle have two ETL tools: Oracle Warehouse Builder (OWB) and Oracle Data Integrator (ODI). The latter one (ODI) is a new thing, and I would expect it to be an ancestor which will replace OWB in some (possibly long) future - but some people may want to kill me for such forecast. ;-) Anyway, those are rather expensive tools, and Oracle have "nothing" for free - they actually have some things, like JDeveloper, but it works best with their database which is free only for non commercial use, and with some additional limitations. ;-)

If you want to start with data warehousing concept you should read one of [Ralph Kimball](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247) or [Bill Inmon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764599445) books (or both, as they represent different concept) - it't important to know the concept first. After that, you should try to find your ETL tool. I am not sure, but Oracle generally is keen on Inmon's concept.

You can experiment with Talend Open Studio first, which is free, and yet very functional. When you know it, you will be able to easilly switch to other tool, as they are generally very similar.